# Are there validated measures to perception of decision making process alignment?

Tags: decision-making

I want to test an idea about how the perception of decision making process alignment with another party influences the tendency to accept information from that party. For example, if my wife and I both consider the cost, nutrition, and the presence of a toy when considering breakfast cereals, I'm more likely to take her cereal recommendation when I go to the grocery store. Likewise, if somebody else only considers taste, I'm less likely to heed his advice.

Looking in the literature, I can't seem to find any measures of decision making process alignment between two people. Does anybody know of a related construct that has been validated?

Answer (score 1):

The following article addresses the issue of decision-making process alignment:

Clemen RT (2008) Improving and measuring the effectiveness of decision analysis: Linking decision analysis and behavioral decision research. In T Kugler, JC Smith, T Connolly, Y-J. Son (eds.) Decision Modeling and Behavior in Complex and Uncertain Environments, Springer, New York: 3-31

Additionally, the following article presents another specific measure which was used to validate the group alignment among the participants by following a particular decision-making process:
[Supporting Multicriteria Group Decisions with MACBETH Tools: Selection of Sustainable Brownfield Redevelopment Actions. Group Decision and Negotiation](http://rdcu.be/njCD)